# Barcodescanner plugin phonegap issue

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins

I did a barcodescanner plugin for phonegap, it works great on Phonegap Developer app, but when I compiled it using

```
Build.phonegap.com
```

When you press the button, it won't work, it does nothing! Can you help me Please?

Comment: hi, can you post your script or logs ..

Comment: @SuryaKrishy https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner this is the plugin

Comment: did you add <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" /> in your config.xml file?

Comment: @SuryaKrishy no,  im going to do it

Comment: @SuryaKrishy i tried it now. Not working either